# Plumbing - Existing Building Water Fixtures Supply Units and Operational Demand

Tags: mechanical-engineering, plumbing

If you have an existing building that is several stories, I would like to know the best way for assessing the water supply fixture units demand.

If you upfit one of the floors, the new fixture demand requires a larger size than the riser, but you really don't know anything about the operational usage of the facility, how would you measure the facilities operational water flow rate usage for any of the specific water risers?

Comment: Start by number of people per floor, average daily use at times of day.

Comment: I would presume there is some kind of standard formula or method for this. At least for new buildings there will probably be something like minimum required capacity depending on number of stories, apartments and expected use. So maybe have a look into a local building code.